# Display maximum 5 words in each title using only JS

Tags: javascript

This is a code, ive used to maximize 5 words in each title

```
<script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      var limitWord = jQuery(".description").html();
      limitWord.val(limitWord.val().substr(0, 5));
    });

</script>
```

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: Please explain the issue clearly.

Comment: @TareqMahmood need to display only 5 word in each title. this code only give 5 characters now.

Comment: 5 word or 5 characters?

Comment: `trim`, `split` by spaces, `slice` first five, `join` by spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `split` function,

I have created a simple jsFiddle however it can be improvemed :)

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nbj8ch45/

html

```
<div class="title">
this is a title with many different words
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(function()
{
    var text = $('.title').text();
  var words = text.split(' ');
  $('.title').text(words[0]+' '+words[1]+' '+words[2]+' '+words[3]+' '+words[4]);
});
```

Comment: What if there are less than 5 words?

Comment: @Kay I did state it can be improved :)

Answer (score 1):

this might help you

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var limitWord = jQuery(".description").html();
limitedWord = getWords(limitedWord);
});
function getWords(str) {
 return str.split(/\s+/).slice(1,6).join(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are your example working

http://jsfiddle.net/2ad3cb3p/5/

```
var limit = 5;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var descs = $(".description");
  descs.each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).html().split(" ");
    var newTxt = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < limit ; i++) {
      newTxt += txt[i] + " ";
    }
    $(this).html(newTxt);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use **split()** function

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     var limitWord = jQuery(".description").html();
     var res = str.split(" ");
  });

</script>
```

In res[0] to res [4], you have the 5 words, see in:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var limitWord = jQuery(".description").html();
  limitWord.val(limitWord.val().split(' ').slice(0, 5).join(' '));
});
```

you can try this

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var limitWord = jQuery(".description").html();
  var arr = limitWord.split(' ')
  var str = "";
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length && i<5; i++){
    str += arr[i] + " ";
  }
  jQuery(".description").html(str)
});  
</script>
```

heres a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shLyLc0k/